# What is different between IE7 refresh button and press on URL bar enter?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

Facebook sdk script does not load when I press on IE7 refresh button, but it's loads when I press enter. How diferent it's works? P.S. it works nice on Mozilla.

Comment: This should be on superusers. Not programming related.

Comment: Do you mean that when you hit the Refresh button, no request is being sent to the server? Have you examined your HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the refresh button resubmits the last request sent by the browser, whereas pressing return in the URL bar submits a GET request for the specified URL.  So sometimes they will do the same thing, but sometimes not, for example if the last request was a POST.

Comment: What I understand that facebook cache some js files and on refresh button it doesn't reload. Is it IE7 bug or facebook SDK bug?

Comment: @user: That doesn't sound like a bug, but a feature: try Ctrl+F5 instead, that'll reload the file, even if the cache settings prevent doing a round-trip.